# Wait return from async task method

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

I'm beginner in code and I have spent hours of searching the solution to my problem.

I'm on a silverlight application which works with different web services and I call them with asynchronous method (I have no choice cause I am using silverlight), and the goal was too wait the return of my method before continue the execution of the application.

This is how my methods look (they are in a static class named `Services`) :

```
private static Task<ObservableCollection<Demande_GetNb_Result>> DemandeGetNbAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<Demande_GetNb_Result>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<Demande_GetNb_Result>>();
    ABClient aBClient = new ABClient();
    aBClient.Demande_GetNbCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };

    aBClient.Demande_GetNbAsync(((App)Application.Current).User.IdUser, true, true, true, (int)Constantes.Statut.Is_Waiting);
    return tcs.Task;
}

public static async Task StartFamille()
{
    ListInfos = await DemandeGetNbAsync(); // ListInfos is a Static variable on my Services class
}
```

and I call this method in other class like this :

```
var result = Services.StartFamille();
```

I want to wait until result has value before continuing the execution, but it doesn't work and I can't find a simple solution that I understand. The execution continue without waiting that a value is assigned to result.

Comment: "but it dont works" - what doesn't work? What did you try, and what happened? Normally you'd call that method from another async method, and await the result... (Note that the method will return very quickly...)

Comment: when i call StartFamille in my code (on an other class than "Services"), the code after the call continue and dont wait that my methods in my "Services" class are finished (DemandeGetNbAsync is not finish to execute). Maybe i should not call "Services.StartFamille" directly like this ? thanks !!!

Comment: I think you should read up on what `async` is about more... read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i had already read it but i will try to understand it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns `Task`. Try to add await operator.

```
var result = await Services.StartFamille();
```

Moreover, DemandeGetNbAsync method should return variable of `ObservableCollection<Demande_GetNb_Result>` type and use await operator as well.

Comment: I cant add await operator like this, i have "the 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier". thanks for ur answer !

Comment: @EZI Please, add your point why it is wrong. It is interested personally for me.

Comment: @Nimp: Then you make the calling method `async`.

Comment: Thanks all for your answer ! I think i have resolve my problem, i will see more and read again the msdn link posted before and i will post my solution.

Comment: @StephenCleary and RredCat were right, i have changed the calling method with async and void return and it have works !